# How do I check all pip packages for packages installed globally using sudo?

Tags: python, linux, pip, sudo

I installed a few `pip` packages using `sudo`, and I would like to go back and remove all of those so I may install it using `--user` (or however it is recommended to install things).

Comment: `sudo pip freeze`

Comment: @Selcuk ...that's not what I am asking. I want a list of all packages installed globally onto my system.  I do not want a list of packages installed onto the local directory.

Comment: What do you mean by "local directory"? Python packages are not installed in any directory; they go to the `site-packages` directory of the interpreter/virtualenv. You should clarify your question if this is not what you are asking for.

Comment: When you install a pip package without root, it installs it for the user, not globally. This is one of the preferred way to install pip packages.

When you install pip packages using root/sudo, they get installed globally onto the system.

However, I was not aware you weren't supposed to install pip packages using root/sudo. I am trying to find out if there was a way to check for all packages installed using root/sudo, and not packages that were installed using `--user` or without root/sudo.

Comment: I see. I can't test this at the moment but `pip freeze --user` _should_ list the user installed modules only.